# How to dowload many files or folders from sharepoint

Tags: windows, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I have a problem, I can't download more than one file or any folder to my local drive from sharepoint via web client.
When I select more than one item, the download button disappears.
Ideally, I would like to download the entire library, but I can not find how.
I'm also interested in how to download multiple selected files or folders.
The account I work with has full permissions.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0Jih.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeIyZ.png)

Windows server 2019
Sahrepoint 2019
MSSQL 2019

In Google, unfortunately, I could not find how to do this, all I found was that there was a download button and no problems.